# Transferring data over bluetooth-serial module with C #

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I need to transmit multiple 8-byte-packets  over bluetooth-serial link. I am using JY MCU bluetooth-serial module. On the PC side, I have a C# application running that communicates with the COM port.

Considering 115200 baud, each 8 byte packet should take 8*8/115200 = 0.555 milliseconds.

The problem is that one in every 4 packets takes up to 39 milliseconds which completely destroys all the timing.

For measuring times, I am using stopwatch component of .net framework.
output from C # application:

---

Sample # 583 : 39.126841990471 ms

Sample # 584 : 0.7883273789593 ms

Sample # 585 : 0.93885067781563 ms

Sample # 586 : 0.884708368788226 ms

Sample # 587 : 8.65278575619526 ms

Sample # 588 : 1.05558303203074 ms

Sample # 589 : 0.870116824511337 ms

Sample # 590 : 0.888932236868378 ms

Sample # 591 : 39.0876752137277 ms

Sample # 592 : 1.02639994347697 ms

Sample # 593 : 0.820198383564084 ms

Sample # 594 : 0.960737994230964 ms

Sample # 595 : 15.2051571125331 ms

---

Note that each sample contains 8 bytes of data

Comment: Does consistency go up if you lower your baud rate? On a similar note when I switched to using bt 4.0 I noticed better connection times. Are you using the same bt versions on both host and client?

Comment: Baud rate of this module can't be changed with software. i will visit lab tomorrow and see if consistency changes.
Not too sure about bt versions right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Dogma #1: There is no such thing as a guaranteed timing in the bluetooth world.

Just consider a device dropping a frame (e.g. because your microwave oven just switched on) - the time to understand the frame as lost is substantial. Additionally the connect/disconnect as shown in your first sample is lengthy. If one of the devices uses e.g. a bluetooth mouse or is discoverable, all bets are off.

Long story short: Bluetooth messages have no consistent timing - if you want to keep timing information, include a timestamp in your payload.

Comment: Thanx for the advice.
But why does every 4th packet shows significant error? I was thinking that adding a buffer or something like that might improve the timing?
Actually this C# app is simulating an EEG device so timing is really important.

Comment: A real EEG device will allways transmit the timestamp with the sample if connected wirelessly- exactly because wireless has no guaranteed timing.

Comment: Okay. But for adding more data in each packet I will need to increase the baud rate. Can you suggest me how to go beyond 115200? Things would be much easier if I could communicate at 1382400 bps. (C# doesn't let me open COM port at anything higher than 115200 despite that it is a virtual COM port)

Comment: First of all: Does it need to be opening a COM port? Can't you use `\\.\comX` as a file?. Next: Is a virtual COM port the best solution? What about a PAN and IP sockets?

Comment: 1)i am at a beginner level actually so I am using the regular serialport.open, serialport.write instructions.
2)Bluetooth module installs a virtual COM port on computer through which I communicate with the device
3)I have no idea about PAN and IP sockets

Comment: thanx for your time.. Can you tell me how to open com port as a file?

Comment: 1 - Try to open a file called `\\.\comN` instead of serial port comN, after setting the baud rate from the control panel. 2,3: You would need to read up on these concepts.

Comment: Maximum baud rate appearing in control panel is 128000, not much faster than 115200.

Comment: So this is the max your virtual com port can do. How many samples/second do you have and how many bytes are a sample?

Comment: The bluetooth module is capable of up to 1,382,400 bps.. I have verified it by communicating the bt module with STM32f4 discovery kit. It is the PC platform that is causing problems.
btw EEG is doing 128 samples/sec, each sample is 8 bytes wide.

In all, I have 768 samples. If I transmit all the data at once, it should take 768*8*8/115200 = 0.426 seconds. But it takes more than 7.5 seconds just to transmit the data.

I have a USB to serial converter that too spawns a virtual com port. Using exact same settings, this converter transmits entire data is almost 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried a different Bluetooth dongle on the PC? Maybe it is some archaic Bluetooth 1.0 model? The driver comes to mind also, it might just set a maximum speed of 128000 for no good reason.

Comment: May be.. I'll try a different module.
Thanx for your support! I really appreciate it.